# Get always returns null instead of the correct value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

I am working on get/set method. However, I can't get the correct value for Get. It always return a null somehow.

the value has been defined here:

```
public string SubPath

iPageAdminView.subpathfolder = context.ExecutionObject.CmscontentParentType[0].ParentType.AttachmentSubFolder;
```

Get/Set

```
public string subpathfolder
    {
        get
        {
            return SubPath; // It always returns a null instead of the correct value. 
        }
        set
        {
            SubPath = value; // It returns the correct value here
        }
    }
```

Can someone help? What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: So when do you try to access `subpathfolder`?

Comment: When I test this, it thinks that you're trying to declare a class, because of "Private" being uppercase.

Comment: put a breakpoint on your setter (SubPath = value), are you sure its not being set to null (i.e. ParentType.AttachmentSubFolder returns null)?

Comment: @NDJ: I did try. It returns the correct value instead of null.

Comment: what is iPageAdminView?  It looks like you have the SubPath and subpathfolder locally to a class, but are setting the property on another instance (i.e. IPageAdminView)

Comment: FYI, rejecting an edit that someone does to help your post follow the SO rules will cause them to ignore your future questions.